# trigger observable few miliseconds after finishing typing in the text field

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I use angular4 and RxJS

Basic assumption is that: when the user enters single letter in the textfield I trigger some getData() function (keyup event), get the data and display below the textfield

I would like not to trigger the function and get the data immediatelly after the user enters a letter but to let him enter full phrase, wait for example 300 miliseconds and finally trigger the function, get the data and display

so the flow I would like to achieve is similar to that:

```
myService.getDataAsObservable
.whatToDoHere?
.subscribe(data => ...handle and display the data...);
```

one solution is to wrap it all into setTimeout(), but it would be much better to do it fluently in an observables' style

I have once seen the solution for that problem, but cannot find it again..

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `debounce` operator:

```
myService.getDataAsObservable
.debounce(300)
.subscribe(data => ...handle and display the data...);
```

Here is the visual explanation:

```
var someObservable = getDataAsObservable('---x---x---x---|');
var someDuration = 300;  //                              '--------|';
var expected =            '---------------------------------------x---|';
```